# How to aproach deleting and undo deleting Items from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I make word game and i want to have posibility to remove text from edit text and get it back to recyclerview item.I did it but my item number is just growing or moving for one field.Here is my code.
This is aproach i tried already but as i mentioned when delete item all items move for one place,than i tried to remove and then add item from edit text,and this causes adding new item every time.So is any way to get position store it and then retrieve it exactly to place from which is taken

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        edit.setText(edit.getText() + adapter.getItem(position).toString().toUpperCase());
        edit.toString().toUpperCase();



      // mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(Asocijacije.this, R.raw.clickbutton);
        if(on==true){
            MediaPlayerWraper.play(Asocijacije.this,R.raw.clickbutton);
        }



       for(int i=0;i<suggestSource.size();i++){
           //index   dr element
          ListaSlova.add(i,position);
          itemClicked=ListaSlova.get(i);
       }

      //  suggestSource.remove(position);
       suggestSource.set(position,"");




        simpleArray = new String[suggestSource.size()];
        suggestSource.toArray(simpleArray);
      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        int numberOfColumns = 6;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
       adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, simpleArray);

        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);







     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
       adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, suggestSource.size());
        lvl.setText("lvl: " + String.valueOf(curquestion));

    }
    public void obrisi() {
     //   mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(Asocijacije.this, R.raw.obrisi);
        if(on==true){
            MediaPlayerWraper.play(Asocijacije.this,R.raw.obrisi);
        }



        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        tapped+=1;

        if (text.length() >= 1) {
            edit.setText((text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)));
          String lastL = text.substring(text.length() - 1);

            suggestSource.remove(ListaSlova.get(itemClicked));
            suggestSource.add(ListaSlova.get(itemClicked),lastL);
             //suggestSource.remove(itemClicked);


            edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            simpleArray = new String[suggestSource.size()];
            suggestSource.toArray(simpleArray);

            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            int numberOfColumns = 6;
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
            adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, simpleArray);
            adapter.setClickListener(this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      //  adapter.notifyItemInserted(suggestSource.size() + 1);
        //    adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(suggestSource.size() + 1, suggestSource.size());
          //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            //  adapter.notifyItemInserted(suggestSource.size()+1);


        } else
            edit.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e) from step 2 it explains how to set in adapter and how to remove your item.

In your `Activity` or `Fragment` create a new `ItemTouchHelper` using our `SwipeToDeleteCallback` and attach it to the `RecyclerView`.

```java
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new 
            ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeToDeleteCallback(mAdapter));
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

to delete (still in Adapter):

```java
public void deleteItem(int position) {
    mRecentlyDeletedItem = mListItems.get(position);
    mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition = position;
    mListItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    showUndoSnackbar();
}
```

Comment: This is only for Undo last item i did it but i need it for:Look from grid layout where I click i send item value to Edit text:Now when i press delete button i want to get back all LEtters from EditText to their previous positions in Grid recycler.From where i took it with onClick

Comment: Oh yeah it's not used for undo all item in one onClick

Answer (score 0):

1- You can create public static List in your activity class.

2- define it to be the list that u need to pass to the recyclerview.

3- pass it to the recyclerview as a parameter to show.

4- get it in your adapter.

5- you will have a position of every item in your adapter which is the same of the index of every element, so when you need to remove an item you can do this:

```
    list.remove(position);
```

and you will get it removed.

6- if you need to keep the deleted items to show later or anything you can create another list in your activity class for deleted items and before you removed it, add it to your another list.

Comment: I did it but when take fro mlist where i saved position it adds item one postion + or - not on same place even i saved correct position